# Graphics programs in Codeblocks

Tags: c++, c, runtime-error, codeblocks, bgi

I've tried running and going through everything I can find on the net to fix the issue but it just doesn't work.
So far I've done:

Downloaded Codeblocks 13.12 (as well as tried with 16.01) with mingw setup.

Added graphics.h and winbgi.h files to the include folder in Codeblocks, mingw.
Added libbgi.a to lib similarly.

Linked the library by going to Compiler Settings->linker settings.
also added the words on the right side:

-lbgi -lgdi32 -lcomdlg32 -luuid -loleaut32 -lole32

The program compiles just fine. I've fixed an error in the graphics.h file which had a double declaration of int right as well as explained in the stack overflow as well as other answers on how to run graphics in codeblocks.

Everytime I run a code, Codeblocks says program.exe has stopped working as soon as it encounters initgraph

Comment: Please provide source code or anything useful to understand what's happening. Did you check the return value `graphdriver` from `initgraph()` call ?

Comment: You'll need to provide more detail than that. For starters, your question should include the shortest snippet of code required to replicate the problem. I'd suggest you look at "The Forger's" windows tutorials. http://www.winprog.org/tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

I have been through that as well. 
Just do one thing. Download codeblocks ep from [here](http://codeblocks.codecutter.org).

Then do the same with this codeblocks ep. download winbgi.h...Everything just the same way you did with codeblocks!